Wyoming-openwakeword fails at startup
Running on Raspberry pi 4 (8gb):
Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
64 bit
I am trying to setup wyoming satellite but get this failure on both the raspberry pi bullseye 32 bit (Pi0 2W) and 64 bit (Pi4).
I have tried the following:

uninstall existing numpy and install opencv-python
uninstall numpy and reinstall numpy

wyoming-satellite has no errors…
Not sure what else to do. Here is the error I get from wyoming-openwakeword:


please do not post a picture of text ... post the text instead

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The following error occurs when running wyoming-openwakeword:
Jun 18 12:15:22 pi4 run[664]: AttributeError: _ARRAY_API not found
Jun 18 12:15:22 pi4 run[664]: ERROR:root:Unexpected error in wake word thread (alexa_v0.1)
Jun 18 12:15:22 pi4 run[664]: ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
What I have read is that this issue (ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import) is related to numpy and opencv_python incompatibility. I have tried to find a compatible version of numpy and opencv_python to no avail. I tried a couple of different versions of numpy/opencv_python.

pls add updates to your query. Don't add them as comments

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78641150/attributeerror-array-api-not-found
